# 'namespace used like a type' error when converting XAML to HTML

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

Coders, I am trying to convert a XAML string to HTML using a library I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/matt/converting-rtf-to-html) , but I have a problem with creating a new instance of the object that would let me use the library. I already added a reference to the library in my Asp.net project and I would like to use it in a WCF file.

The problem is that whenever I try to instantiate a new object with the new keyword, I get an error that says:

> 'MarkupConverter' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'.

Here is my code, notice that I am creating a new object just like the example shown in the library link above, please help:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MarkupConverter;

namespace AspPersonalWebsite
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1 //: IService1
    {
        private string connectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
        private IMarkupConverter markupConverter;        

        [OperationContract]
        public string convertXAMLToHTML(string XAMLtext)
        {
            string htmlText = "";
            markupConverter = new MarkupConverter(); /*PROBLEM IS HERE*/
            htmlText = markupConverter.ConvertXamlToHtml(XAMLtext);
            return htmlText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code block does not show correctly!

Comment: @abatishchev did u remove the using statements in editing..i saw them when the post is unedited

Comment: @Eyad Since the class library is not yours, changing it may be a bit challenging but generally (actually always) we should not use the same name for a class as a namespace: [Don't Do it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15007801/1232087)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Confusion is arising because the actual type is `MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter`, the compiler seems to think your `new MarkupConverter` is an attempt to use a namespace as a type, rather than an attempt to instantiate a type inside your `using` namespace.

Simply change your problem line to:

```
markupConverter = new MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter(); /*SOLUTION HERE!*/
```

..and you should be fine.

Answer (score 8):

In your case, you have a namespace `MarkupConverter` and a class with the same name (`MarkupConverter` again).

In the line `markupConverter = new MarkupConverter(); /*PROBLEM IS HERE*/` the compiler is unable to tell that you intent to use the class. Since a namespace with the same name is present, the compiler picks it instead, because namespaces are linked with higher priority by the compiler.

You can resolve this by using the **complete name** of the class:

```
// supposedly MarkupConverter is the namespace of the MarkupConverter class
markupConverter = new MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter();
```

An alternative way to providing the fully-qualified name of the class is to use an alias, which takes the form of `using {ALIAS} = {Fully qualified name of Type| Namespace}`. Note that the `{ALIAS}` part can be any valid identifier.

The alias you can place either in your usings:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MarkupConverter;

using MarkupConverter = MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter; // this is aliasing
```

or after the namespace declaration:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MarkupConverter;

namespace AspPersonalWebsite
{
    using MarkupConverter = MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter;

    ....
```

and you're good to go! At this point, if aliases are present, the line

```
markupConverter = new MarkupConverter()
```

will correctly pick the `MarkupConverter` class, because explicit aliasing has higher priority than the automatic binding done by the compiler.

Comment: The second solution sounds very elegant, but unfortunately I get `Namespace 'Topns' contains a definition conflicting with alias 'MarkupConverter'`. (Topns is the top namespace above the MarkupConverter namespace).

Comment: When aliasing inside a namespace, you must still use the full type name in the alias. For example `using MarkupConverter = Topns.MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter`, where `Topns.MarkupConverter` is a namespace containing the `MarkupConverter` class. To resolve further confusion of the compiler, you may also use `using MarkupConverter = global::Topns.MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter` In general the `global::` prefix should be rarely used, but it is useful if your own namespaces conflict with the ones from a referenced assembly

Comment: I wrote `using MarkupConverter = global::Topns.MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter;` but then `protected MarkupConverter foo;` fails to compile, with this error: `Namespace 'Topns' contains a definition conflicting with alias 'MarkupConverter'`.

Comment: This is hard to gasp into without the source code at a hand, but what comes to my mind is that you change the `MarkupConverter` alias to something different and unique and use it instead.

Answer (score 2):

That is pretty much self explanatory,

`MarkupConverter` is a namespace ,so shouldn't be used as a class to create an object

Comment: maybe that could get you some sort of weird badge.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show the `MarkupConverter` class you use please? The error is maybe in its declaration. In Where namespace is it? What is your file structure?

Maybe you have created a `MarkupConverter` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a "using MarkupConverter" statement in the usings section. That will import all classes from that namespace.

Comment: I did but the user abatishchev has removed it when he edited my post!!

Comment: abatishchev has reverted their removal, it seems. So this answer is kind of obsolete now, I would say?