# Net Core empty project shows Controller Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

When I start a new empty project there is an error in the  .net core project:

> Controller is a namespace but is used like a type.

Am I missing some packages?

Comment: Also related: ['namespace' but is used like a 'type'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007727/namespace-but-is-used-like-a-type)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you've missed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package. Just add it to `project.json` and things will be OK.