# Activity is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I was working on the code and accidental faced this error message

> Activity is a namespace but is used like a type

```
namespace MainAppHotelXamarin
{

public class AdminActivity : Activity
{
    string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "HotelDb.db3");



    Button BtnOrderFood;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Admin);

        BtnOrderFood.Click += BtnOrderFood_Click;

        CreateDB();
    }

    private void BtnOrderFood_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(FoodOrdersListActivity));
    }

    public string CreateDB()
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);

    }
}
}
```

All of my activities have this error too, even those ones that I didn't edited them recently.
Anyone knows what's wrong with it? Thanks beforehand

Comment: Did you name (a part of) your Project Activity?  A Folder perhaps?

Comment: If you want us to help, you'll have to share some code that demonstrates the problem, otherwise, all i can do is to shoot in the dark. Could it be that you've named your namespace "Activity"?

Comment: @Henk Yes I did, but I'm working on it for days and it was working good till now.

Comment: @Arik I know but I was not allowed to add the code because there was too much code and I hadn't more detail to add here. I haven't named my namespace "Activity"

Comment: You have more than one  namespace. So look through your project.

Comment: Problem solved. When I was creating new activity to my project in Activity folder, there was a `.Activity` after the namespace.Problem solved by deleting that one. Thanks All.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['namespace' but is used like a 'type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007727/namespace-but-is-used-like-a-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem solved. When I was creating new activity to my project in Activity folder, there was a `.Activity` after the namespace.Problem solved by deleting that one.

The (advisable) default in Visual Studio is to keep Folders and namespaces in sync. So the best course here is to rename that folder to `Activities` and add that as the tail namespace to all your classes already in that folder.

Activities is also the usual name for that folder in a Droid project.

Answer (score 0):

You have some namespace called "Activity". So you need to either:
1) Rename your namespace
2) Specify class with exactly namespace `Android.App.Activity`

Comment: Problem solved. When I was creating new activity to my project in Activity folder, there was a `.Activity` after the namespace.Problem solved by deleting that one. Thanks you.