# Web Service can not find in MainActivity.cs in xamarin android OR how to call web service from mainactivity in xamarin android

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am Trying to call a web service in Xamarin Android Project. But when adding service reference in my project and trying to create reference of that web service it says **'HelloService' is a namespace but is used like a type**.

**MainActivity.cs**

[image: MainActivity.cs]

**Solution Structure:**

[image: Solution Structure]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['namespace' but is used like a 'type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007727/namespace-but-is-used-like-a-type)

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate. so please explain me how to access webservice in my activity class using HelloService namespace....

Comment: Hi, I can't find `HelloService` class, there is only `HelloService` folder, can you show me your `HelloService` class? And please remove the space in your `Web References` folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with xamarin.android, it's an issue with naming, i assume you have something like this.

```
namespace HelloService
{
    class HelloService
    {
}
```

Don't use same name for classes and namespace, more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15007801/5611425)

Comment: i don't understand. I want to access the specific medhod that i wrote in my webservice class by creating HelloService object declaration. I don't think this will help me that you provide me above reference.

Comment: You have to be very specific in what you are asking for, web service is a general term, please provide more info on your `HelloService` class.