# In C# => Executing Class Library in Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll, console-application

I wish to create a menu-driven program which will be classified on the basis of some aspects (say operators or any other thing).

I have created a console application project and given "sample" as the namespace. 
In the sample, I have created a menu in the Main()

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\nMenu Driven Program");
        Console.WriteLine("\n<--------List of Available Options-------->");
//Creating a list to Select from
        Console.WriteLine("\n  Select Any of the Following Function :");
        Console.WriteLine("\n_________________________________________");
        Console.WriteLine("\n1. Arithmatic Operators\n2. Logical Operators");
        Console.WriteLine("\n3.Misc1\n4. Misc2");
//Accepting a normal string
        string b = Console.ReadLine();
        int d;
// Following converts string into an integer
        Int32.TryParse(b, out d);

//Following code is used to create menu-driven program
        switch (d)
        {
            case 1:
//Here I wish to call one class library 
                break;

            case 2:
//Here I wish to call another class library
                break;
//And so on.    

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nWhat you wish to do?\na. Continue the Program\n\nb. Exit the Program");
                char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                if(c=='a'||c=='A')
                {
                    Main();
                }
                else
                {
                    Exit();
                }                  
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now, I created a class library in which I will store three classes (let's just consider) increment, division, and multiplication.

But, I am unable to call that class library.
When I directly input the name of class library in Switch "Case" it gives me CS0118 error stating that "Sample" is just a namespace but used like variable.

In my class library, I have created three different class and again a Main()
which will show the list of available operations.
Eg.If arithmetic operators, then the Main in class library will consist Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, etc.

Comment: What does the class in your library look like and how did you try to call it? It helps if you include the line that caused the error

Comment: `namespace Sample {class MyClass {public static void Main() {...}}}` - do not forget to declare `class`; `Main` should be *within* the class.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007727/namespace-but-is-used-like-a-type and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/

Comment: Please include what one of the commented out calls to a class would look like...

Comment: OP, you cannot "call a class library." The only thing you can call is a method. That method might belong to a class that is contained in the library. If all you're writing out is the namespace, that isn't going to do anything.

Comment: @JohnWu, I understand now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, complex answer, got it after a bit scratching my head. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @rene, sorry I forgot to mention about on which line the error occurs. BTW, I also simply forgot to mention the Main() which I created in Sample Class Library. You may refer to the reply marked as answer by me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CS0118 error stating that "Sample" is just a namespace but used like variable

Error CS0118 occurs when you try to create an instance of a namespace, or otherwise use the namespace as though it's an instance of a class. See [this documentation post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0118) for more information.

From you description my assumption is that you need to call the main in each of your 3 classes depending on what the user selected. Consider the following code...

```
switch(d)
{
    case 1:
        Sample.Class1.Main();
        break;
    case 2:
        Sample.Class2.Main();
        break;
    case 3:
        Sample.Class3.Main();
        break;
    default:
        // default processing here
}
```

This is assuming your namespace is called Sample and the methods are defined as static in the classes in your library.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the concerned issue. As your name is, you indeed are "Fabulous".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the Class library project. I'm assuming you created them in the same solution. Make sure both are busing for the same. Net version say 4.6.
To add a reference, expand the project explorer, look for references, right click, and choose Add, then find the class library and check the checkbox. 
If you have the productivity tool Resharper installed, it makes fixing these sorts of things much faster.

Comment: Actually, I did add the reference, I just wanted to call the Main() from the class library.
I used the solution provided by "Fabulous", which I have marked as "Answer".

Thank you for your response.