# Problem with DbContext prop on asp net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have created an api in asp net core 2.1 and I have three layers inside it (PwP.Web).
In the layer (PWP.DomainClasses) I defined a class with the following specifications and in the layer (PWP.DataLayer) a class called PWPDbContext and inside it I want to define the user class as prop but it warns and is not used, how this Solve the problem?

User.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text;

namespace PWP.DataLayer.User
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(32)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string imageAddress { get; set; }

        //
        public virtual UserInfo.UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PWPContext.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PWP.DomainClasses.user;
namespace PWP.DataLayer.Context
{
    class PWPDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public PWPDbContext(DbContextOptions<PWPDbContext> options): base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Expertise> Expertises { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }
        public DbSet<STFile> STFiles { get; set; }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your `User` is declared inside `PWP.DataLayer.User` (from your posted code) but looks like it should be in `PWP.DomainClasses.User` namespace? This seems to involve some conflicted naming of namespace & classes.

Comment: You mention 3 layers, but have not provided the code for your "DomainClasses" layer.  Can we see that?

Comment: You have to add "using  PWP.DataLayer.User" in PWPContext.cs.

Comment: The user.cs class exists in DamainClasses

Comment: Hi @Eliot, Try to rebuild the DomainClasses library, and re-add the library in the web or DataLayer application. From the screenshot, in the DomainClasses library the folder name begins with a capital letter ("User"), but when you add the library in the web or DataLayer application, it using a lowercase letter (`using PWP.DomainClasses.user;`). So, I assume might be the library not update, try to re-install it. Besides, about the 'namespace' but is used like a 'type', perhaps the class name is same with the namespace, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007727/).

Answer (score 0):

From this line of code:

```
public virtual UserInfo.UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
```

It can be seen that you named the class with the exact same name as it's namespace.

You should differentiate between them.

**Don't (!) do that:**

```
namespace UserInfo
{
    public class UserInfo
    {
    }
}
```