# used like a type but is a namespace

Tags: c#, powershell

I have below code in my UnitTest case where I am trying to test a Powershell cmndlet. If I write *"PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();"* inside my method below I keep getting error as "powershell is a namespace but is used like a type". What wrong am I doing?
used like a type but its a namespace

```
public class CosmosDataTests
 {
   [Fact]
   public void TestGetRecordings()
    {
           PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
                // Arrange.
                var cmdlet = new GetRecordingsCmd()
                {
                    Project = "Demo"
                };         
}
```

Comment: Seems you have a namespace called "Powershell" in your code.

Comment: I agree with Klaus: check for `namespace Powershell { ...` in your code.

Comment: no i dont have Powershell as namespace but i have a project which i have refrenced to this project and there i have namespcae as org.data.Powershell as namespace. i am using this in my current project as using org.data.Powershell

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['namespace' but is used like a 'type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007727/namespace-but-is-used-like-a-type)

Comment: no..i have checked that my namespace and class name is different

Comment: You can always use the class name with full namespace: `var ps = System.Management.Automation.Powershell.Create();`

Comment: now its says system does nt contain a definition fr management but i hv using system.management.automation

Comment: Are you sure you have referenced System.Management.Automation.dll to your project? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.create?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0

Comment: yes i am sure.. its there.. i have using System.Management.Automation in there

Comment: Adding a "using ..." is not enough. You have to *reference* the assembly, too.

Comment: ok, i still hv the same error on Powershell.Create() as used as type but is a namespace