# Wpf facebook app errors:

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook

Currently i'm making a *wpf facebook application* and in my code continuously the two errors are coming:

**First Error**

> 'FacebookApi is a namespace but is used as a type'

**Second Error**

> The type or namespace name JSONObject could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference)?

Comment: Show your code please!
Also, the compiler errors already tell you the problem.

Comment: Can you add 'FacebookAPI' as an import to your file? The same for JSONObject. See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15481116/561485. Please provide more information, e.g. your file, if this does not resolve it.

Comment: Yes i'v already added 'FacebookAPI' but still the error is coming. Thats why i cnt understand what is the problem.